# If $x+\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{z+\frac13}}=\frac{118}{51}$ find $xyz$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to solve this algebra problem.

> If $$x+\cfrac 1 {y+\cfrac 1 {z+\cfrac 1 3}}=\frac{118}{51}$$
> find $xyz$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply  trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression in this regard.)

Comment: Actually WA gives the answer. See the section for continued fraction: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=118%2F51

Comment: This isn’t my home work I’m just doing this for fun

Comment: Note that if you divide $118$ by $51,$ the quotient is $2$ and the remainder is $16,$ so you have $$ \frac{118}{51} = 2 + \frac{16}{51}. $$

Comment: For the record, here is how the original poster expressed the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVwz8.jpg

Answer (score 6):

I will presume that $x,y,z$ are intended to be positive integers.
\begin{align}
\frac{118}{51} & = 2 + \frac{16}{51} = 2 + \frac 1 {\left( \frac{51}{16} \right)} = 2 + \cfrac 1 {3 + \cfrac 3 {16}} \\[15pt]
& = 2 + \cfrac 1 {3 + \cfrac 1 {\left( \frac{16} 3 \right)}} = 2 + \cfrac 1 {3 + \cfrac 1 {5 + \cfrac 1 3}}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is simply the simplest way of getting the values of $x, y $ and $z$ ! Fantastic approach... Keep it up, @Michael Hardy !

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham : Thank you.

Comment: You are always welcome... btw, would you mind helping m with this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757372/is-it-possible-to-make-a-statistical-classifier-using-the-inverse-square-law-in ?

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to rewrite the left hand side a bit. This leads us to:

$$x + \frac{3z+1}{y(3z+1)+3} = \frac{118}{51}$$

From this it follows that the denominator on the left must be a multiple of 51, therefore:

$$y(3z+1)+3 = 51N$$ where N is a natural number. For the numerator we then find the equation:

$$51Nx + 3z + 1 = 118N$$

Let us try $N = 1$. We can easily verify that $z = 5$, $y=3$, $x=2$ is a solution. It is possible that other solutions exist. This should be carefully checked.

Answer (score -1):

Write:

$\begin{align*}
   x + \frac{1}{y + \frac{1}{z + \frac{1}{3}}} - \frac{118}{51}
     &= 0 \\
   \frac{((153 x - 354) y + 153) z + (51 x - 118) y + 153 x - 303}
        {153 y z + 51 y + 153}
     &= 0
\end{align*}$

If the denominator isn't zero, the numerator must be:

$\begin{align*}
  ((153 x - 354) y + 153) z + (51 x - 118) y + 153 x - 303
    &= 0 \\
  153 x y z - 354 y z + 153 z + 51 x y - 118 y + 153 x - 303
    &= 0
\end{align*}$

It is seen that this can't be written as a function only of $x y z$. You can e.g. set any pair of variables to zero and get a matching value for the third, and that doesn't always make the denominator zero.

This has no solution.

Comment: If you set any pair of variables to values of your choice and get a solution for the third, then that gives you a value of $xyz,$ and in most cases that makes your denominator $0.$ So by that reasoning one would conclude that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: By my calculation, we have $$ x+\cfrac 1 {y+\cfrac 1 {z+\cfrac 1 3}} = \frac{3xyz + xy + 3x + 3z + 1}{3yz + y + 3}. $$ Your denominator is just $51$ times mine:
$$
153xyz + 51y + 153 = 51\big( 3yz + y + 3 \big).
$$
But I wonder about the numerator that you got. $\qquad$